# extra dots in tables

Tags: tables, labels

I want to have table numbers in table title displayed as, for example

> ```
> Table 4.5. This table is a rebel
> ```

I achieve this by doing:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{table}.}
```

The problem is that when I use \ref{} in the text to link to the table, latex also returns "Table 4.5." instead of just "Table 4.5". This is particularly ugly at sentence ends when it can happen "Table 4.5..", where the last dot is a full stop.

So, how can I get "Table 4.5." in the table title, but not when I use \ref{}?  Thanks

```
\documentclass[10.5pt]{report}
\usepackage{librecaslon}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\presectionskip}{-1\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\postsectionskip}{0.3\baselineskip}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\@startsection
    {chapter}{1}{0mm}%% name, level, indent
   {\presectionskip}% % beforeskip
    {\postsectionskip}% % afterskip
    {\fontsize{18}{18}\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
    {section}{1}{0mm}%% name, level, indent
    {\presectionskip}% % beforeskip
    {\postsectionskip}% % afterskip
    {\fontsize{10.5}{10.5}\bfseries}}% % style
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection
    {subsection}{2}{0mm}
    {\presectionskip}
    {\postsectionskip}
    {\fontsize{10.5}{10.5}\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection
    {subsubsection}{3}{0mm}
    {\presectionskip}
    {\postsectionskip}
    {\fontsize{10.5}{10.5}\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\newcommand*{\defeq}{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape,url}
\usepackage[round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf},justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=240mm, top=24mm, bottom=24mm, left=18mm, right=18mm,headsep=7mm}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\newcommand\cites[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s\ (\citeyear{#1})}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{Page \thepage}
\usepackage{titling}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookc{\vspace{-0ex}}
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\vspace{-0ex}}
\usepackage{comment}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{ \arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete document, starting from `\documentclass`. Otherwise we do not know which document class and which packages you use. All of these may affect the way tables are numbered. If you are in a plain `article` class, remove your `\renewcommand` and try `\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fnum@table{\tablename\nobreakspace\thetable.}
\makeatother` in the preamble.

Comment: @gernot: I've added the preamble. Is that enough or do you need further info? (The complete document is hundreds of pages long). both your suggestion and the suggestion of Bernard below work. However, in my list of tables, now I get no dot after the table number. I would like the dot in the list of tables as well (just not in the main text when I mention the tables)

Answer (score 2):

The best is to load the `caption` package and to use `\captionsetup{labelsep=period}`.

Furthermore, if you put the caption *before* the table (as should be, according to the typographical tradition), you'll have a decent vertical spacing between caption and table.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard This works. However, in my list of tables, now I get no dot after the table number. I would like the dot in the list of tables as well (just not in the main text when I mention the tables) .

Comment: Don't  you have a dotted line in your list of tables?

Comment: What I have now is the following. For example:
2.1  Summary Statistics .............. 34
2.2 Some title here.....................46

and I want

2.1. Summary Statistics .............. 34
2.2. Some title here.....................46

Comment: I see. The number is on the left side. Since you load `titlesec`, it should be  possible to add the dot if you format  the list of figures with its companion package `titletoc`.

Comment: I've taken a look at the documentation. You might try loading `titletoc` with option `[dotinlabels]`. (Not sure whether making it work requires an explicit formatting of the table of contents with titletoc).

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try

Comment: If you have any problem, feel free to ask. I didn't propose a solution, because I never used titletoc for  such lists.